# What is Exit(integer) and how to make use of it in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, exit-code

I know nothing about C, C++ or any lower level than PHP. I take a glance into Codeigniter 3 codes at github and found it's added [exit status code constants](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/constants.php), i.e we can do:

`exit(EXIT_DATABASE)` means `exit(8)` or `exit(EXIT_UNKNOWN_CLASS)` means `exit(5)`

what is differ between

```
echo 'Configuration file not found';
exit(3);
```

and just

`exit('Configuration file not found');` ?

What is the purpose of using `exit(integer)` in php ? it doesn't print anything, does it? I also check [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and google some but still not get it clear. **How to make use of this?** where i can get reference about this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It gives the caller a hint as to what the outcome of running your script is.

This can be useful in php if you are running a script with `exec` or `system` and you need to behave differently based on the outcome of running the script.

```
<?php
   $output = array();
   $error = null;
   exec("/path/to/php cleanData.php", $output, $error);
   if ($error){
       Logger::log($error, $output);
       die("Sorry I was Unable to Clean the Data\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running some of your scripts from console, you can determine any error from script's response code.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.exit.php

You can use the integer to return errorcodes which can be used by former programs. For example you can use NAGIOS for monitoring your servers and therein call a PHP-Script, e.g. to make a DB call to count something, whatever. At the end of the script you return 0,1,2,3 as a returncode to tell NAGIOS if the check you are doing is ok, warning, critical, or unknown. These returncode is then used by NAGIOS for further actions, like sending email to an admin etc.

So you can use the exitcode to give information to other progams who use your PHP-script

Answer (score 0):

I think manual is quite clear about that let's look at this example

```
//exit program normally
exit;
exit();
exit(0);

//exit with an error code
exit(1);
exit(0376); //octal
```

It is used for exit from the program from the console either with error or not, so you can keep track of them, and it's exaclty the same as `die()` function.

> if status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

As you said the function also allow you to print directly your error if you will use it with a `string` instead of an integer

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.

[**Reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)